# Why am I getting sporadic "role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda" errors in API gateway logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

We're experiencing sporadic failures when API Gateway is attempting to call an existing Lambda function. Unlike other questions about this error, it is not a new function that I'm having problems getting to work in the first place; this is an existing function that hasn't changed in almost a month, and the permissions/roles in place also haven't changed. Today between 15:21 and 15:25 UTC we had about 10 errors. The API Gateway logs show the following for each of them:

```
Endpoint response body before transformations: {"Message":"The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda."}
```

Since that time, the lambda and API gateway have been working together normally.

I verified that the role defined for the function can be assumed by Lambda, according to the trust relationships established for it and visible in the Trust Relationships tab of the role's summary in IAM in the AWS web console.

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Do you have CloudTrail enabled? If you do, I recommend opening a support case with AWS.